# For an integral domain $D$, $na = 0$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}, n\neq 0$ for *some* $a \in D - \{0\}$, then $D$ is of finite characteristic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, alternative-proof

> For an integral domain $D$, $na = 0$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}, n\neq 0$
>   for *some* $a \in D - \{0\}$, then $D$ is of finite characteristic.

My attempt:

Let $x \in D$, then

$na \cdot x=0$ since $na=0$ by hypothesis.

$$
\begin{split}
na \cdot x &= (a+a+ \cdot\cdot\cdot +a)x \\
&= (ax+ax+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+ax) \\
&= a(x+x+\cdot\cdot\cdot+x) \\
&= a \cdot nx \\
&= 0
\end{split}
$$
since $na \cdot x=0$. So now we have $a \cdot nx=0$ and we know $a \neq 0$ $\implies nx=0$ since $D$ is an integral domain which has no zero-divisors.

So we have shown that for $n \in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$, $nx=0, \forall x \in D$. So $D$ is of finite characteristic.

Besides some feedback about my proof, I would also be interested in some alternate approaches.

Comment: I would like to add that $x \in D, x \neq 0$ since the definition for characteristic requires the ring element to be non-zero. The rest of the proof remains the same.

Comment: You can simply assume $x=1_D$. Then, essentially as you argued above, the sum of $n$ copies of the unit multiplied by $a$ becomes the sum of $n$ copies of $a$. Since $a\neq0$, we must have $n\cdot1_D=0$.